# Find all possible sequence list from single list c#

Tags: c#, linq

i want to find all possible sequence elements from list using c#

numbers are in incremental order if it is sequence i have to split the array

Example array : int[] array = {1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10}

expected output as all possible sequence list: {1,2,3} , {5,6} ,{8,9,10}

Can someone help me on this ?

code

```
    for(int i=0;i<array.Length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]== array[i+1])
        {
           // i want to get all possible sequence of elements
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `Xn` is missing you have to split, right? What have you tried and what doesn't work? Why you get 2 upvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    private static List<List<int>> FindSequence(int[] array)
    {
        var result = new List<List<int>>();
        var tempList  = new List<int>{array[0]};
        var lastResult = array[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if(lastResult + 1 == array[i])
                tempList.Add(array[i]);
            else
            {
                result.Add(tempList);
                tempList = new List<int> {array[i]};
            }
            lastResult = array[i];
        }
        result.Add(tempList);
        return result;
    }
```

I've used `List<List<int>>`, that could be changed to `List<int[]>` if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another implementation:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> FindSequences(IEnumerable<int> input, int step = 1)
    {
        int currentIndex = -1;
        int sequenceStartIndex = -1;
        int lastValue = 0;
        foreach (int i in input)
        {
            ++currentIndex;

            if (currentIndex == 0)
            {
                sequenceStartIndex = 0;
                lastValue = i;
                continue;
            }

            if (lastValue + step != i)
            {
                yield return input.Skip(sequenceStartIndex).Take(currentIndex - sequenceStartIndex);
                sequenceStartIndex = currentIndex;
            }

            lastValue = i;
        }

        if (currentIndex > -1) //collection was not empty
        {
            yield return input.Skip(sequenceStartIndex).Take(currentIndex - sequenceStartIndex + 1);
        }
    }
```

- [+] Allows results streaming
- [+] Works on any collection type or array
- [+] Allows defining custom steps
- [-] Involves more iterations than a `List<int>`-based solution

Comment: Down-voter, would you state the reasoning behind your vote?

Comment: Did not (down-)vote, but wouldn't results streaming require this method to be async?

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti by streaming I meant retrieval upon request. When you `foreach` the result from a 'yield-returned' `IEnumerable`, a new `IEnumerator` instance gets created, and it's possible that the `IEnumerator` gets disposed/collected  before the last element (e.g when exiting the loop upon a particular condition). In that case, the rest of the elements won't have to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a max value that is not very big, and only for zero or greater values I would use an Aux array auxArray[maxValue] of zeros, go over the array of numbers once and update all the crrent value in the auxArray to one.
auxArray[array[i]] = 1;
then I would go over the auxArray once and for every 1 found in the array keep going until you reach a zero. and the next bunch will start once you find another one.

example on how to fill the array:

```
arr[0,1,5,6];
auxArray[6] = {0};
for(i=0; i< 4; ++i)
{
   auxArray[array[i]] =1;
}
```

so now all you need to do is a for loop (i=0; i<6; ++i) and as long as there is a sequence of ones you stay on the same sequence.

Another way to go, is to get the next min value out of the numbers array. if it is greater than the last min value by one- they go together. if not, start a new numbers batch.

A third way to go is to sort the array. then just go over it and check the diffrence is 1 for same bunch.